# PHP script not running inside a form tag

Tags: php, html

I have recently installed Apache 2.4.7 server, as well as, PHP 5.5.10. I'm just beginning to learn PHP. I'm currently working through the w3school's tutorial on form processing with PHP, but I can't get a particular example to work. Does anyone here see an error?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>PHP Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    // define variables and set to empty values
    $name = $email = $gender = $comment = $website = "";

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
    {
        $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
        $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
        $website = test_input($_POST["website"]);
        $comment = test_input($_POST["comment"]);
        $gender = test_input($_POST["gender"]);
    }

    function test_input($data)
    {
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        return $data;
    }
?>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>">

        Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
        E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
        Website: <input type="text" name="website"><br>
        Comment: <textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea><br>

        Gender:
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male<br>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

When I visit this website, I get a quote and a greater than sign before the input field name specifically: "> Name. When I submit the form, the URL shows as

```
http://127.0.0.1/%3C?php%20echo%20$_SERVER[
```

I can't enter the exact contents of the URL, because this website won't let me, but the %3C actually shows up as a less than sign. The %20 shows up as a space. So, the problem is that the php script inside the action tag does not run. The action variable is then filled with the php script instead of the location of the current page. Why is the PHP script not running inside my form tag?

Solution:
Thank you everyone for helping. Abhik Chakraborty your comment led me to the solution. No, I did not save my file with a .php extension. I changed the extension to .php and it worked perfectly. I would have posted this as a solution, but I have to wait eight hours because I don't have enough reputation points.

Comment: did u save the file with .php extension ?

Comment: You could just leave the action empty and it would post to the current page

Comment: Look at the end of this line: <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>"> There is your ">

Comment: @RasmusStougaard - not the point, this problem still shouldn't happen.

Comment: @Pavenhimself there's no issue with the syntax of that line

Comment: @Ryan You are correct. Was only meant as a suggestion and not a solution anyways

Comment: @Ryan Removing the last "> will remove "> before his input field. So yes

Comment: this is because he  may saved the page as filename.php.html

Answer (score 0):

If you leave action tag undefined it will use current location.

somefile.php:

```
<form method="post">
```

will execute the same uri

Answer (score 0):

Replace `action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>"` by `action=""`

Answer (score 0):

Remove action tag in your form. bcoz action is not mandatory for current page.
if u given $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . concatinate to your full path.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, this should work

```
<?php echo "<form method='post' action='".$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]."' >";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"
```

try this one this is the method posted on w3school to refer to self page at till now faced no problems with it.

Answer (score 0):

you are not processing the data you can try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>PHP Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    // define variables and set to empty values
    $name = $email = $gender = $comment = $website = "";

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
    {
        $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
        $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
        $website = test_input($_POST["website"]);
        $comment = test_input($_POST["comment"]);
        $gender = test_input($_POST["gender"]);
    }

    function test_input($data)
    {
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        return $data;
    }
?>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>">

        Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
        E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
        Website: <input type="text" name="website"><br>
        Comment: <textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea><br>

        Gender:
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male<br>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
    Name: <?php echo $name?> <br />
      Email: <?php echo $email?> <br />
      Gender: <?php echo  $gender?> <br />
      Comment: <?php echo  $comment?> <br />
      Website: <?php echo  $website?> <br />
</body>
</html>
```